# Webpack bundle error: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack

My web app uses Webpack 5.45.1 as a module bundler and the only library - ethereum `web3.js` 1.4.0.

```
// webpack configuration file
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/dev'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
}
```

The entry point contains one single statement: `import Web3 from 'web3';`

Executing of the resulting bundle with a browser ends in the following error:

```
assertion_error.js:486 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'custom' of undefined
    at eval (assertion_error.js:486)
    at eval (assertion_error.js:500)
    at Object../node_modules/assert/build/internal/assert/assertion_error.js (index.bundle.js:1063)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.bundle.js:6721)
    at eval (assert.js:38)
    at Object../node_modules/assert/build/assert.js (index.bundle.js:1052)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.bundle.js:6721)
    at eval (index.js:3)
    at Object../node_modules/console-browserify/index.js (index.bundle.js:1624)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.bundle.js:6721)
```

I found it out, `undefined` is a value of this expression: `require('util/').inspect`.

Can anyone provide a hint on how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you want to use web3 in the browser or in a client environment you have to manually include the prebuilt **"node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"** in to your html with a script tag. That's the way it described in the documentation or you just get it from a cdn.

You should only do this:

```
import web3 from "web3";
```

if you want to run it in the nodejs runtime (Server side code or in the Command line).

If you insist on building this yourself then you have to clone the web3.js git repository and run `npm run build`, then get the **/dist/web3.min.js** file, and include it in a html script tag of your page, which is still pretty much the same thing and unnecessary.

Read the documentation carefully and see for your self.
[web3.js github repo](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js)

Comment: Hi Benjamin. In my case the issue was a buggy plugin (`NodePolyfillPlugin`). But still your answer can be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, in my case the problem was in `NodePolyfillPlugin`, which has a bug related to a circular dependency. I opened the [issue](https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin/issues/18) on github.